# What are the semantics of using retain vs. copy for a property of type NSMutableSet;

Tags: objective-c, memory-management, copy, retain

I have been using the most excellent Accessorizer to auto-magically generate setters/getters for my Obj-C code in Xcode. Recently a change was made in Accessorizer:

old version of Accessorizer:
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSMutableSet *setA;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSMutableSet *setB;

new version of Accessorizer:
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSMutableSet *setA;
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSMutableSet *setB;

Sadly, the new version crashes my code. In my code I do the following:

```
self.setA = [[[NSMutableSet alloc] init] autorelease];
self.setB = [[[NSMutableSet alloc] init] autorelease];
```

// ...

```
[self.setA minusSet:self.setB];
```

The above line of code works fine using the old way (retain) but crashes using the new way (copy). Clearly something is wrong here. I rely on Accessorizer extensively. Could someone please clarify the implications of using copy/retain in the context of NSMutableSet?

Thanks,
Doug

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're property type is a *mutable* set, you most likely want a retain. If it's a *non-mutable* set (aka NSSet), Apple's guidelines say to use copy rather than retain.

The distinction is that there's an expectation that a mutable set is going to change. A non mutable set is expected to remain unchanged, but if it's declared as retain, someone could set it to a mutable set and then change the contents unexpectedly.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, this is a "feature" of properties.  When you set a property that's declared as `copy`, then the generated setter is going to invoke `-copy` on the object.  Unfortunately, in the case of mutable objects, this results in an *immutable* variant.

In other words, the object returned by `[myMutableSet copy]` is **not** mutable.

If you need the set to be mutable, then you *must* use `retain` (or override the setter to use `mutableCopy` instead of `copy`).

I filed a bug on this (rdar://8416047), but it was closed as "works as designed".  (Because there's really no way for the setter to know if an object is mutable or not)